# Cannot access 'FlowRowScopeInstance': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm missing some plugins in android studio

I tried to use weigh(1f) in a Row on modifier but the message came up: Cannot access 'FlowRowScopeInstance': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout'.

Can you help me how to resolve that?

Thanks

Comment: You should provide a whole lot more info, type of Android installation, version and such.